# Use of Hyphen or Minus Sign in Matplotlib versus Compatibility with Latex

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdflatex

I am having the problem where a pgf created using matplotlib.pyplot outputs hyphens instead of minus signs, which Latex cannot interpret.

I attempted to use the solution found [here](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/minus-sign-instead-of-hyphen-in-negative-axes-labels-td14882.html), but it changes numbers from integers to floats (i.e. 2000 becomes 2000.0) in the tick labels. I am looking for a solution that fixes the signs but keeps the default formatting in pyplot otherwise.

Any ideas? Example below.

*myplot.py*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

def math_formatter(x, pos):
    return "$%s$" % x 

plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[-1,-2,3,4,5,6,7])

axis = plt.gca()
axis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(math_formatter))
axis.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(math_formatter)) 

plt.show()
```

*mylatex.tex*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \input{myplot.pgf}
     \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you plot without the formatter argument, you get the standard formatting as int, but latex will not recognize the hyphens as minus signs. If you use the formatter argument, all int will become floats.

I am looking for a solution where the hyphens are changed to minus signs but no matter the argument (int or float or otherwise) the ticks will behave like the default behavior of pyplot (except the hyphens are minus signs).

Comment: In what part of the graph --- the ticks? Can you give us a a snippet of code responsible for outputting your graph so we have something to work with?

Comment: just modify the formatters to force the resulting label to be an int.

Comment: @PatrickCollins I added an example. Yes the issue is in the ticks.

Comment: @PaulH That will not fix the problem for when I want floats. I am looking for something that provides the default behavior of pyplot but just changes the hyphens to minus signs.

Comment: Great question thanks. I would be interested to know what are the incentives to embed you figures in Latex like that instead of saving and importing them in latex as pdf?

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien The .pgf show clearer and are more easily manipulated in my experience. I've had trouble with .pdf when trying to import into LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to simply to cast as an integer.

```
def math_formatter(x, pos):
    return "%i" %x
```

Answer (score 16):

Recent versions of Matplotlib use, by default, the typographically "correct" (this is debatable) [unicode minus signs (U+2212)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Minus_sign) to express negative numbers, and not the [ASCII hyphens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus). On my system, the ASCII hyphen is interpreted without any problem in Latex, but the unicode minus sign is not by default.

Using a `FuncFormatter` with the expression `return '%i' % x` as you proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201310/use-of-hyphen-or-minus-sign-in-matplotlib-versus-compatibility-with-latex/32018501#32018501) converts the minus sign to a hyphen and is a valid solution for Latex compatibility. In addition to this solution, below are two additional alternative solutions that could be used to solve this problem with a more "system-wide" approach.

**matplotlib : use hyphen instead of minus sign**

The ASCII hyphen (which is interpreted correctly by Latex by default) can be used instead of the unicode minus sign to express negative numbers in matplotlib. As per the documentation (http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/api/unicode_minus.html), it is possible to do this by doing:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
```

**Latex : use unicode minus sign**

If you prefer to use the minus sign instead of the hyphen, you can add this in the preamble of your Latex document:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{$-$}
```

Latex should then recognize the character `U+2212` and express correctly the negative numbers with a minus sign. Below is the output I get with Latex with hypens (top) and with minus signs (bottom):

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Well explained and solution included.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
def math_formatter(x, pos):
   return "${}$".format(x).replace.("-", u"\u2212")
```

Comment: I tried it and the axis still results in values like -200.0 instead of -200, any other ideas?